# Text field gone missing when TableViewer gets filled

Tags: swt, jface

Issue happens on Win10. Eclipse 4.13.0.

I got a JFace TableViewer above a Text widget in a GridLayout. Whenever I fill the Table with content, the Text widget disappears. If I configure the shell as FillLayout it works, but that's not what I want because I've got some widgets not wanting to grab any space (like the search field, the separator, etc.).

I can't seem to find the problem, any advice?

```js
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Link;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class TestDialog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setBounds(10, 10, 800, 600);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        Label separator = new Label(shell, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
        separator.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

        Link link = new Link(shell, SWT.NONE);
        link.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore");
        link.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));

        Text txtSearch = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SEARCH | SWT.ICON_SEARCH | SWT.CANCEL);
        txtSearch.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));
        txtSearch.setMessage("Enter search phrase here");

        TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

        Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
        table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

        Group grp = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
        grp.setText("MyGroup:");
        grp.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
        grp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

        Text txt = new Text(grp, SWT.WRAP);

        List<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            entries.add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore");
        }

        tableViewer.setInput(entries);      

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is being expanded to show all of the lines and this is pushing everything below the table out of the window.

You need to specify a height hint for the table:

```java
Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1);
data.heightHint = 200;
table.setLayoutData(data);
```